# Retrieving AccountId from contract_ref

Tags: ink, contract-references-approach

Following this example for ink! smart contracts

https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/trait-dyn-cross-contract-calls/lib.rs

we have

```
incrementer: ink::contract_ref!(Increment),
```

and by entering the relevant AccountId that the contract is deployed at here

```
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(incrementer: AccountId) -> Self {
        Self {
            incrementer: incrementer.into(),
        }
    }
```

we get a reference to the contract

Question: How can we retrieve the AccountId having the incrementer contract reference

Note: I understand that I can create another storage variable of type AccountId and store this in the constructor like

```
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(incrementer: AccountId) -> Self {
        Self {
            incrementer: incrementer.into(),
            incrementer_address: incrementer,
        }
    }
```

but I am wondering if I can avoid the extra storage of such variable incrementer_address and instead derive the AccountId of the incrementer: ink::contract_ref!(Increment) inside a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the account id of the contract ref by calling `to_account_id()` on the contract ref: https://docs.rs/ink/latest/ink/trait.ToAccountId.html

```
let contract_ref =
    MyContractRef::new(<params>)
        .endowment(0)
        .code_hash(...)
        .salt_bytes(...)
        .instantiate();
let account_id = contract_ref.to_account_id();
```

Later on you can recover the ContractRef with

```
let contract_ref: MyContractRef =
    ink::env::call::FromAccountId::from_account_id(my_contract_acct_id.clone());
```